# Does Ocra screen reader come on Edubuntu by default?

Tags: edubuntu, orca

I am working with visually impaired children in Kenya and would like to know if Orca screen reader comes with Edubuntu and whether it would work with the various educational packages on Edubuntu.

Many thanks

Martin Muckle

Answer (score 1):

Edubuntu is basically Ubuntu with an additionally installed meta package. Therefore all applications that are available for Ubuntu will also be available in Edubuntu, including Orca. From version >=11.04 you will also have a [package selection](http://www.stgraber.org/2011/02/22/edubuntus-installer-ready-for-11-04/) on installation of Edubuntu.

[Orca](http://live.gnome.org/Orca) is an integral part of the GNOME desktop and should therefore run fine in Edubuntu as GNOME is also the default desktop environment there.

However some of the [applications bundeled with Edubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Edubuntu/AppGuide) make use of KDE. Depending on the application in question you may need to test the Orca acessibility for these individually.

Unfortunately Orca is not yet sufficiently integrated in Unity, therefore using the classical GNOME desktop is recommended.